# Error while adding a new record from text boxes to database

Tags: c#, winforms

Error when saving data to database. DataAdapter.Fill(ds,"Table") is throwing SqlException saying error while converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

```
private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Measurement where ID = @ID", con);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Fill(ds, "Measurement"); //(SqlException Unhandled)Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCellNo.Text.Trim()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell Number");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            dr = ds.Tables["Measurement"].Rows[0];

            dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text.Trim();
            dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
            dr["Shirt"] = txtShirt.Text;
            dr["Pant"] = txtPant.Text;
            dr["DueDate"] = txtDueDate.Text;
            dr["Date"] = txtDate.Text;

            cb.GetUpdateCommand();
            da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you don't need my help anymore, many professionals are answering your question :)

Comment: @AbZy The problem now is it can't find dr = ds.Tables["Measurement"].Rows[0]. It says no position at row 0. I followed your instructions

Comment: My eyes hurt just by seeing you're performing database operations in a method called `btnSave_Click_1`

Comment: Well, I am just a beginner. Once I get grip on the subject, I can work on n-tier architecture ;)

Comment: @KiritiK You can't handle the same code for new rows. You need to do it the same way you did before asking the first question. by creating a new row.

Comment: @AbZy: When I create a new row, My edit mode is not working and when I fix my edit mode then the new row is not working. Is there any way around ? or I just have to use a new button ?

Comment: @KiritiK there are more efficient ways to do it but for now you could just have two buttons, one for new and one for update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",txtID.Text);
```

`txtID.Text` is a string that you need to convert to an integer.  See [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: Int.TryParse Worked like charm! Thanks LarsTech

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `@ID` to the database as a string (nvarchar from your databases perspective). You need to cast/convert `txtID.Text` to an appropriate numeric value when setting up the `@ID` command parameter. I suspect you need to call `int.Parse(txtID.Text)` (assuming ID is an integer in the database).

As an aside, you may also need to guard against invalid ids being entered in `txtID.Text`. In this scenario you could use:

```
int id;
if (!int.TryParse(txtID.Text, out id))
{
    //an invalid id was supplied so stop processing and warn user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `txtID.Text` may not be an integer. You should convert it first. Try:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
```